# Global variable named type is hiding the built-in type() function in Lua

Tags: c++, lua

A C++ program I'm working on is using lua for configuration. It sets up several lua functions using a hardcoded script:

```
luaL_loadbuffer(pmLuaState, headerscript, strlen(headerscript), "header script");
```

It then loads the configuration lua file (that calls the previously mentioned functions):

```
luaL_loadfile(pmLuaState, filename)
```

Unfortunately, the Lua configuration file uses a global variable named type, so attempting to call the built-in type() function from my headerscript fails with a Lua error:

```
attempt to call global 'type' (a string value)
```

Due to the constraints of my scenario, I am unable to edit the offending config file. I'm wondering if there's a way to explicity state that I want to use the built-in type() function.

I'm new to Lua, so if there's a better way to load in these scripts that will avoid this global hiding issue, I'm open to it (but again, I cannot edit the config script).

Lua version: 5.1.4

Comment: Could you bind the type function to another name before loading the config, then restore the type global to point back to the function after loading the config? Or will this screw up stuff (e.g. functions in config that assume the global type will be the redefined global variable instead of the function).

Comment: This might work. How would I go about binding the type function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the global variable has been modified, the value cannot be recovered- that is, you must prevent the script from setting _G.type in the first place, or store the value beforehand. The second is relatively trivial

```
local type = type -- problem solved
```

or you can use environments to solve this problem. This is a pretty common script to run.

```
local loadedmodules = {}
import = function(filename)
    if (loadedmodules[filename]) then
        return loadedmodules[filename]
    end
    local env = {}
    local func = loadfile(filename);
    local envmeta = {
        __index = _G -- changed thanks to comments
    }
    setmetatable(env, envmeta) -- Allow the imported script to read only our globals
    setfenv(func, env) -- set func's _G to env
    func() -- Load the script
    return loadedmodules[filename] = env -- Set the result and return it.
end
```

This would be the C++ equivalent of automatic header guards and macros being automatically scoped to the defining file.

Once you define this script from Lua, you can load it from C++ and call it relatively trivally. I don't recommend doing any extensive Lua logic from C++, the stack-based API is very hideous.

Comment: This works! However, I accepted Glenn's answer as he responded first, but if it is possible to accept two answers I'd like to nominate your's as well for the cleanliness of the environments approach.

Comment: `if` in `__index` is superfluous. `__index` is called only if table[key] is `nil`. Also you may want to reuse the metatable table (but not the environment object itself though).

Comment: @Shadow503: You should accept whatever answer is best (for the sake of future readers), not whichever is first. You may change accepted answer.

Comment: And, finally, no need for `__index` to be function. `__index = _G` is faster (and more concise).

Comment: @Shadow503: I agree with Alexander, accept the best answer, not the one that comes first.  I upvoted this answer once I understood exactly what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

You should [sandbox](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) config files so that they would not affect the global environment of the whole program.

Call [`lua_setfenv()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setfenv) with the empty table as an environment on the chunk, returned by `luaL_load*()`.

Update: if config file needs stuff from global environment, expose it with metatables.

In Lua:

```
setfenv(chunk, setmetatable({__index = _G }))
```

(Read the manual to realize how to write it in C.)

Note that this method of sandboxing is too weak for untrusted code. For example, config would be able to do stuff like `table.concat = myevilfunction`. See Wiki page linked above for full-blown sandboxing approaches (which should be overkill in your case though).

Comment: But the config script needs the functions available in the script header chunk he loaded earlier.  He'd have to update the environment table to include those functions, would he not?  And then isn't the overriding of the `type` going to happen anyway?

Comment: @Glenn: You can modify the environment's metatable to allow read-only access of _G, and transparent writes to env. Check out my answer.

Comment: @DeadMG - Ah, I see.  Treat the config file as the import, not the script header which is loaded into _G.  I was thinking about it from the other way around, where the config script is "importing" the header script.